# Lexical analyzer (Flex) throws lexical error after space following by tokens (and more)

Tags: c, regex, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

As i run the lexical analyzer with the following example, it seems like it cannot recognize empty space between tokens, and tokens generated with the regex showed down.

lexical analyzer (Something.l) :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int yylex();
//void yyerror(const char *s);
void yyerror (const char * msg)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "C-like : %s\n", msg);
  exit(1);
}
int line_num = 1;

#include "y.tab.h"
#define T_eof   0
%}


%option noyywrap 


letter  [A-Za-z]
digit   [0-9]
id  letter(letter|digit|'_')*
num [1-9]digit*('.'digit*)?
string  '(digit|letter)*'
Empty   [\t\r]|" "
line    [\n]

%%

{line}      { line_num++ ; }
"mainclass" { printf("MAINCLASS ") ; return  (MAINCLASS) ; }
"public"    { printf("PUBLIC ") ; return (PUBLIC); }
"static"    { printf("STATIC ") ; return (STATIC) ; }
"void"      { printf("VOID ") ; return (VOID) ; }
"main"      { printf("MAIN ") ; return (MAIN) ; }
"println"   { printf("PRINTLN ") ; return (PRINTLN) ; }   
"int"       { printf("INT ") ; return (INT) ; }
"float"     { printf("FLOAT ") ; return (FLOAT) ; }
"for"       { printf("FOR ") ; return (FOR) ; }
"while"     { printf("WHILE ") ; return (WHILE) ; }
"if"        { printf("IF ") ; return (IF) ; }
"else"      { printf("ELSE ") ; return (ELSE) ; }
";"     { printf("Q ") ; return (Q) ; }
"=="        { printf("EQUAL ") ; return (EQUAL) ; }
"<="        { printf("SMALLEReq ") ; return (SMALLER) ; }
">="        { printf("BIGGEReq ") ; return (BIGGER) ; }
"!="        { printf("NOTEQUAL ") ; return (NOTEQUAL) ; }
{id}        { printf("ID ") ; return (ID) ; }
{num}       { printf("NUM ") ; return (NUM) ; }
{string}    { printf("STRING ") ; return (STRING) ; }
<<EOF>>     { printf("EOF ") ; return (EOF); }
.       { printf(" lexical error in Line : %d \n ", line_num); exit(1); }
{Empty}+    { printf("EMPTY ") ; /* nothing */ }
[\(\)\{\}]  { return yytext[0] ; }
%%
int main(){
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Running the following example :

```
mainclass Fibonacci {
    public static void main ( )
    {
        int first, second, i, tmp;
        first=0;
        second=1;
        i=0;
        while (i<10)
        {
            i=i+1;
            tmp=first+second;
            println (tmp);
            first=second;
            second=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
MAINCLASS
```

Adding one space in the beggining of the example :

```
lexical error in Line : 1
```

Adding tow or more spaces in the beggining of the example, we have got this output :

```
EMPTY MAINCLASS
```

Removing mainclass and leave the first space and the identifier in the beggining we have got :

```
EMPTY  lexical error in Line : 1
```

Comment: This `id  letter(letter|digit|'_')*` does not mean anything close to what you want it to mean. 1) `letter` is a literal string; you meant a macro expansion `{letter}`, similarly for `digit`. 2) `'_'` needs to match a three-character sequence, since `'` is not a flex metacharacter. Presumably you meant `_`, but a clearer way of writing that whole thing is probably `[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`. Or `[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*`. Personally, I think it's bad style to use macros when a perfectly good Posix character class exists; the Posix character class is clear, while the macro might have errors.

Comment: I don't think I can provide any more analysis without seeing the entire flex input. Also, if you are using the `-l` flag to flex, you'll get odd results. Please don't do that. It should never be used in modern code; it's only there to allow people to continue to compile prehistoric lex programs.

Comment: For reference, [this](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) is everything you need to know about flex patterns. Please read it; it's not very long.

Comment: OK, I tried what you pasted and it doesn't show the problem with space characters. Please show your complete scanner. At an absolute minimum, show the code which produces the "lexical error" message, in its full context. (Did you perhaps put it *before* your rule for matching whitespace?)

Comment: Thank you for replying @rici . I tried to change the ID's regex but there was no difference in the output. I just Posted the complete scanner. Im using the following commands: `flex lexScan.l`  `gcc lex.yy.c -o test`
 and ` ./test < example1.c` .

Comment: Those are separate problems. The `id` definition is definitely wrong.

Comment: It's better for your `.` rule to `return yytext[0];` to the parser and let the parser deal with it as a syntax error, invoke error recovery, etc. That also lets you use `'+'` etc directly in the parser and get rid of all your *flex* rules for single-letter special characters. Quite a win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of rules in a flex file matters, and this is a particular example of that.

You have the rule:

```
.       { printf(" lexical error in Line : %d \n ", line_num); exit(1); }
```

which will match any single character, which includes matching a space character.

Later on in the file (actually, immediately following), you have

```
{Empty}+    { printf("EMPTY ") ; /* nothing */ }
```

which could also match a single space character. But if the token to be matched is a single space, then the first rule will win (precisely because when the same token is matched by more than one rule, the first rule wins).

On the other hand, if there are two spaces, then the pattern `{Empty}+` will match both of them, whereas `.` will match only one. In this case, `{Empty}+` will win, because the longest match always wins.

You should always place fallback rules at the very end of your scanner description (except possibly for `<<EOF>>` rules). That not only ensures that they will work as expected, it also put the rules where people will look for them.

Note that there are a variety of other errors in your macro definitions, some of which are noted in a comment. These will also cause your scanner to reject valid inputs, so they need to be addressed.

By and large, I recommend avoiding macros unless you have very complicated patterns in which the same subpattern appears several times, which is the use case they were intended for. `{Empty}` is not at all descriptive, so it forces the code reader (me, in this case) to search your source file for a definition. You could have used the Posix character class `[[:space:]]`, which is well-known to anyone experienced with Flex. (It includes newline characters, but your newline rule is only used to increment the line number count; you could get Flex to do that for you by simply including `%option yylineno`.)

Comment: Okey @rici , rules' order and wrong definitions were causing the whole issue. Great thanks!